# Derivatives of Matrices, Vectors and Scalar Forms that I can't find in Matrix Cookbook

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors

Does anyone know what the derivative of $\frac{\partial (\bf{x}-\bf{\mu}_x)^T \Sigma(\bf{y}-\bf{\mu}_y)}{\partial \bf{x}}$, where $\bf{x}$, $\bf{y}$, $\bf{\mu}_x$ and $\bf{\mu}_y$ are vectors and $\Sigma$ is a symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix, is? I tried to find the result in the Matrix Cookbook but I could not find it, could someone please explain if they do know?

Comment: Use the fact that $\partial x^T/\partial x = I_N$.

Comment: What about the $\Sigma$ matrix and the other vector?

Comment: $\Sigma$ doesn’t depend on $x$, does it? You’re either overthinking or underthinking this.

Comment: So $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix

Answer (score 1):

Define the vector
$$\eqalign{
v &= \Sigma(y-\mu_y) \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of this vector, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= (x-\mu_x)^Tv \;=\; (v^Tx - v^T\mu_x) \\
d\phi &= v^T dx \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} &= v \;\doteq\; \Sigma(y-\mu_y)\\
}$$